# cross repository branch merge git

Tags: git, git-merge

I have created 2 Git repositories (Dev and staging) and branches b1, b2 and b3 in each of the repositories. Now how can I merge say b1 of Dev to b2 to Staging? Is there anything that can be automated so that I will save my time? Or any hookup scripts can be written to do this?

Comment: Maybe the thread of this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a new remote in the `Staging` repository to point to `Dev`

```
git remote add dev /path/to/repo.git
```

Fetch all from the dev remote.

```
git fetch dev
```

Make sure you are on `B2` of `Staging`. Merge Dev/b1 into Staging b2

```
git checkout B2
git merge dev/b1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that really helped. Going ahead, i believe the same thing can be done from my instance to Amazon hosting server where i have Git installed, i.e., to push the code from my staging to production git of Amazon hosted server. Correct me if i am wrong.

Also if you can help me in writing a script where I can write those series of commands you have explained so that it saves my time in writing the same commands again and again.

Comment: If the answer answered your question, mark it as such. First try to do this alone, if you have any questions you can ask another question on so, I will gladly help

Comment: This is first time for me, so was not aware, my bad. done it though, thanks again !